# Unable to call array of addresses

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have a HelloWorld contract and Keystore contract, both deployed in my truffle console.

When I read the Helloworld's public attribute balance, I get a value.
When I try to read Keystore's public array of owners (addresses), it fails.

Why?

```
contract HelloWorld {
  uint public balance;

contract Keystore {
  address[] public owners;

truffle(development)> hw.balance
{ [Function]
  call: [Function],
  sendTransaction: [Function],
  request: [Function: bound ],
  estimateGas: [Function] }
truffle(development)> hw.balance.call()
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 3, c: [ 1000 ] }



truffle(development)> ks.owners
{ [Function]
  call: [Function],
  sendTransaction: [Function],
  request: [Function: bound ],
  estimateGas: [Function] }
truffle(development)> ks.owners.call()
Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:41471:16)
    at SolidityFunction.validateArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:327892:22)
    at SolidityFunction.toPayload (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:327908:10)
    at SolidityFunction.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:327949:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:316821:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:316812:18
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

EDIT:

Error trying to call with param:

```
truffle(development)> ks.contract.owners(0)
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:41484:16)
    at RequestManager.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329505:22)
    at Eth.send [as call] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:37994:58)
    at SolidityFunction.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:327953:32)
    at SolidityFunction.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:328078:22)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:13
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:59:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:120:6)
    at Console.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:202629:17)
    at ReplManager.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:203345:18)
truffle(development)> ks.owners
{ [Function]
  call: [Function],
  sendTransaction: [Function],
  request: [Function: bound ],
  estimateGas: [Function] }
truffle(development)> ks.owners.call(0)
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:41484:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329530:36
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:325200:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:328229:7)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176415:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176705:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176860:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:176820:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
truffle(development)>
```

Comment: I've tried changing owners to `mapping(address => uint) public owners`; and still get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public getter for an `array` or `mapping` takes a parameter.

`ks.owners.call(0)` should work to retrieve the first owner, `ks.owners.call(1)` should retrieve the second owner, etc.

Comment: Hello, I get a VM exception trying that, please see my question for edited log

Comment: How long is the `owners` array? Perhaps `0` is out of bounds; make sure you've added something to the array first.

Comment: Hi, good catch. I tried calling, I get an invalid number of arguments when I try to add to the array with my function. Full contract + error here: https://gist.github.com/quantumproducer/b1cfdbbb8b04c24e834543518c59a0bb ( Sorry I cannot edit my question yet)

Comment: You're passing an argument to `buyKey`, but it doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Oh that's right -- msg.sender is implicit!

Comment: I still get an errror if I just use ks.buyKey.call invalid RM Response

Comment: You're also trying to `call` it, but you're going to need to send a transaction for it to actually take effect. Something like `buyKey.sendTransaction({ from: '0x123abc', value: 12345 })`. (Caveat: I haven't used Truffle, so I don't know if they're using standard `web3.js` or not.)

Comment: This blog post of mine may help to understand the difference between `call` and `sendTransaction`. (Note that you'll also need to wait in the case of a transaction for it to get mined.) https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/

Comment: Ah, thank you! I can now buyKey then use owners.call(0). However I cannot tell the duration of owners since owners.length is still 0

Comment: How are you checking the length?

Comment: ks.owners.length

Comment: Like you're trying to call that from JavaScript? I would have expected it to be undefined. To my knowledge, the Solidity compiler doesn't generate a getter for array lengths, so you'll need to write your own accessor.